# Installing numpy for python 2.6

Tags: python

How do I install numpy for python2.6?

When I installed the package python-numpy, it was installed in python2.7 (the default in Ubuntu), but not 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you have setuptools installed in your python2.6, you can just do

```
sudo easy_install2.6 numpy
```

which will pull the egg from pypi.python.org and will build and install it.

Alternetively, you can download .tar.gz file from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.6.1), unpack it and run

```
sudo python2.6 setup.py install
```

Due to the fact `numpy` contains code written in C, you will need `build-essential` and `python-dev` packages installed (the latter should be for Python 2.6)

See INSTALL.txt in the tarball for more details